# Web scraping information from the site in PHP

Tags: php, web, web-scraping

I do PHP script, the script must copy the list of publications (from the homepage) and copy the information that is inside these publications.

I need to copy content from my previous site and add the content to the new site!

I have some success, my PHP script copies the list of publications on the home page. I need to make a script that pulled information inside each publication (title, photo, full text)!

For this, I wrote a function that extracts a link to each post.
Help me write a function that will copy information on a given link!

```
    <?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require 'phpQuery.php';

function print_arr($arr){
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($arr, true) . '</pre>';
}

$url = 'http://goruzont.blogspot.com/';
$file = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);

foreach($doc->find('.blog-posts .post-outer .post') as $article){
    $article = pq($article);
    $text = $article->find('.entry-title a')->html();
    print_arr($text);
    $texturl = $article->find('.entry-title a')->attr('href');
    echo $texturl;
    $text = $article->find('.date-header')->html();
    print_arr($text);
    $img = $article->find('.thumb a')->attr('style');

     $img."<br>"; if (preg_match('!background:url.(.+). no!',$img,$match)) { 
$imgurl = $match[1]; 
} else 

{echo "<img src = http://goruzont.blogspot.com".$item.">";}

        echo "<img src='$imgurl'>";
}
?>
```

Comment: if you are copying it from your own previous site to your own new site, why not just re-upload the source to the new site?

Comment: In my case it is impossible!